# tensorflow: self.stack[-1] is not default (list index out of range)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got error message such this:

> IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in get_controller(self, default)
> 3813     finally:
> 3814       if self._enforce_nesting:
> -> 3815         if self.stack[-1] is not default:
> 3816           raise AssertionError(
> 3817               "Nesting violated for default stack of %s objects"
> ```
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

My code like this:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=True,
      log_device_placement=False)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():
        cnn = TextCNN(
            sequence_length=708,
            num_classes=9,
            embedding_size=embedding_size,
            filter_sizes=filter_sizes,
            num_filters=num_filters,
            l2_reg_lambda=l2_reg_lambda)

        ...

        step = 0
        while step < num_epochs:
            x_batch, y_batch = next_batch(training_x, training_y, training_prot_num)
            v_x_batch, v_y_batch = next_batch(validation_x, validation_y, validation_prot_num)
            train_step(x_batch, y_batch)
            currenct_step = tf.train.global_step(sess, gloabl_step)
            if currect_step % evaluate_every == 0:
                print("\nEvaluation:")
                dev_step(v_x_batch,v_y_batch)
                print("")
```

How should I modify this code for fixing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963606/tensorflow-python-nesting-violated-for-default-stack-error-with-custom-graph).

Try removing `tf.reset_default_graph()` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: But if i remove   tf.reset_default_graph(), then an error will appear: Did you reuse Varscope = True?

Comment: Where does the error appear ? And is the code you give really complete ?

Comment: ValueError: Variable weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "<ipython-input-12-1fb4fe3d082b>", line 61, in TextCNN
    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
  File "<ipython-input-14-96bdbe12a7e1>", line 13, in <module>
    l2_reg_lambda=l2_reg_lambda)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

Comment: Your problem comes from the `TextCNN` function. Can't help you if we don't see what's inside that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have a problem in TextCNN function. Thank you!